# Comparative degree usage

Tags: comparative-constructions

> 1. She is **beautiful** than mary.
> 2. She is **more beautiful** than mary.

Are both sentences correct and have same meaning? If not, what is the difference in their meaning?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a comparative form of "beautiful" but you could say "She is **prettier** than Mary."

Comment: @WeatherVane  "more beautiful" is the comparative form of "beautiful". Sentence 1 above is just not grammatical.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty perhaps what I mean is that we need to say "more beautiful" because, unlike "pretty", "beautiful" does not have a comparative form, and that the first sentence would be grammatical if another word, that does have a comparative form, is used. My bad.

Comment: @WeatherVane I see what you meant, now.

Comment: We use capital letters to begin proper names such as Mary.

Answer (score 1):

As  is mentioned in the comments, sentence (1) is incorrect. The word *than* suggests **comparison**, and for that, you'll need a **comparative adjective**. The comparative form of "beautiful" is ***more beautiful***, which is in your second sentence. Sentence (2) is correct for this reason.